# How to assign a set of parameters to a macroeconomic model in Matlab?

Tags: macroeconomics, matlab

I am trying to assign a vector of values `(v= [1/3 0.01 0.5])` to a vector of parameters `(w = [alpha beta gamma])` in order to make Matlab save the entries of the value vector as the parameter values. So for instance the third entry of v should be assigned to the third value in w. Matlab should then save `gamma = 0.5` in the workspace. I was not able to figure out how to do it. My solution always just overwrites the other vector but does not save the entries in the workspace. I hope, someone can help me out.

Comment: I dont get why you just dont define alpha = 1/3 beta=0.01 gamma= 0.5 separately and then if you need it in a vector form just do that with w = [alpha beta gamma]. Wouldnt this do what you want?

Comment: The simplest approach would be to write a function that assigns the parameter set to the structures variables. Hence, para.alpha=v(1);para.beta=v(2), and para.gamma=v(3).

Comment: @1muflon1 I am writing a function which uses the vector as input. In order to vary the entries, I was trying to create something like this.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt thanks a lot. That solves my problem!

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt consider posting it as an answer

Comment: @Hokkaido21 you mentioned that this answer solved your issue - consider accepting it then (by ticking the check mark under votes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my approach to assign a set of parameters to a macroeconcomic model:

```
function para=assign_parameters(v)

if length(v)==3
   para.alpha=v(1);
   para.beta=v(2);
   para.gamma=v(3);
else
   error('parameter input has not correct format of length 3!');
end
```

The advantage is that the parameter set can be changed on the fly. That is, one can assign to the same underlying macroeconomic model a different set of numerical parameters without observing any conflict among the analyzed models. This would allow a quick comparison of model outcomes and ensure a clear as well as consistent model environment.

For instance, the example from the post can be assigned by

```
pm=assign_parameters(v)
```

and if one wants to study a second model like

```
v2=[2/3 1/100 1/2]
```

one should assign this set of parameters to a different structure name like

```
pm2=assign_parameters(v2)
```

Then both sets remain separated and the first parameter set will not be overwritten by the second.